# Does mysql have similiar tool like oracle bulk import and export?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, export, import

One of mysql servers I managed, we need to migrate from AWS RDS to EC2(mysql installed).
Because of too many record in mysql(using mysqldump to export will cost 7 days).
I should find a solution that can reduce down times.
We already try AWS DMS service, but boss ask me find more solution like bulk export.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are going from MySQL to MySQL instance wise, why not just backup the DBs (or tables), copy over the backup files, and then restore to the new server? Why do you need to do export and import transactions to migrate MySQL instances rather than just restoring it all?

Comment: *"Using mysqldump to export will cost 7 days"* is dubious unless your database is on the order of multiple terabytes... and the time it takes to export is irrelevant.   You can migrate from or to RDS with near zero downtime using mysqldump and native replication... so it is not clear what problem you are really trying to solve.  What does it mean, you "already [tried]" DMS?  If you already tried it, you should be finished.

Comment: @MarijuanaTechnologyIT420 RDS is a managed service.  It's not shared hosting, since you have your own VM with your own CPU, network, and disk... but you don't have access to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bulk export then you use mysqldump. If that native utility takes 7 days I don't think anything else is going to be faster.

AWS Database Migration Service isn't great. It doesn't take indexes, autoincrement fields, etc.

A better option could be to replicate from your on-premise database to MySQL in RDS. It will no doubt take longer to populate the RDS database than dump / load, but it means you can seamlessly switch over to RDS without downtime.

If that doesn't fit your needs I suggest you edit your question to expand on your drivers and needs.